# Imprimir matriz para juego Taken

Tags: java

Estoy comenzando a aprender a programar en `java` pero no se por donde empezar, ya que no tengo conocimientos sobre la programación del mismo y espero que la pregunta, no sea muy obvia.

La meta es hacer un juego de consola que haga lo siguiente, por ahora no me preocupo del diseño.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Por lo que pienso nada más crear una matriz hacer que el usuario elija que movimiento quiere hacer, hasta que llegue al movimiento o no.
Pero tengo problemas al crear la matriz, solo quisiera que me la imprima aparte que tampoco me deja meter un caracter `X` en ella.

```
    // Llamo al paquete scanner para que me ayude, cuando ingreso por el teclado
//import java.util.Scanner;

public class takenjuego {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Tomare el juego como si fuera una matriz de n*m
        //En este caso sería una matriz de 2*2
        int n = 2;
        int m = 2;
        //Creación de la matriz 
        int A [][] = new int [n][m];
        // Ahora tengo que llenar la matriz con las condiciones iniciales que tengo 
         A[1][1]=3;
         A[1][2]=7;
         A[2][1]=2;
         A[2][2]=1;
         System.out.print(A);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Para poder introcducir una 'X' tendras que cambiar el tipo de tu matriz de int -> string.En cuanto a imprimir tendras que crear un metodo que reciva una matriz[][] y la recorra con un bucle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para poder introducir una `X` en tu matriz, deberás cambiar la declaración de esta manera:

```
int A [][] = new int [n][m];
```

Por esta otra:

```
String A [][] = new String [n][m];
```

Necesitas que sea de tipo `String`

Ahora para poder introducir los valores a dicha matriz, puedes ayudarte de una función:

```
private static void introducirArray(String[][] a) {
        Scanner insertar = new Scanner(System.in);
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < a.length; j++){
                System.out.print("Inserte Valor: ");
                a[i][j] = insertar.next();
            }
        }       
    }
```

De esta manera, lo que hacemos es recorrer el tamaño de la matriz para poder insertar valores en cada posición.

Ahora, para poder ver los valores introducidos, hacemos uso de otra función:

```
private static void visualizarArray(String[][] a) {
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < a.length; j++){
                System.out.print(a[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Aquí vamos recorriendo cada posición de la matriz y visualizamos su valor que en ella contiene.

Te dejo el ejemplo completo para que lo pruebes:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class takenjuego {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Tomare el juego como si fuera una matriz de n*m
        //En este caso sería una matriz de 2*2
        int n=2;
        int m=2;
        //Creación de la matriz 
        String A [][] = new String [n][m];
        // Ahora tengo que llenar la matriz con las condiciones iniciales que tengo 

         introducirArray(A);
         visualizarArray(A);
   }

    private static void introducirArray(String[][] a) {
        Scanner insertar = new Scanner(System.in);
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < a.length; j++){
                System.out.print("Inserte Valor: ");
                a[i][j] = insertar.next();
            }
        }       
    }

    private static void visualizarArray(String[][] a) {
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < a.length; j++){
                System.out.print(a[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Espero que pueda ayudarte.